# Ionic Disable Requirement Check for JDK Version

Tags: java, angular, ionic-framework, apk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQxe.jpg)

I face this issue from last few weeks and now finally **I SOLVED this issue**  by just Disabling the JDK version check in code.

Search for check_reqs.js in your ionic project platform>android>cordova>lib and comment out the line "const EXPECTED_JAVA_VERSION = '1.8.x';"
Then After comment out the function written for EXPECTED_JAVA_VERSION.

Also run this command: sudo ionic cordova platform add android@9

Now finally you will be able to generate apk.

Thanks for reading this :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQreR.jpg)

Comment: As the Error says clearly you need to upgrade your java version. Install Latest java Version.

Comment: I have a MAC and I tried your solution but it won't work on my side that's why i found this solution